# How to add in "working times" if statement a specify holiday dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, typeerror

I try to figure out how in to the code "if statement" add a specific day(official holiday dates) in month when business does not work. Now it's code works *if day is Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri* and *time is from 09:00 to 15:00* in 24 h format. 
But I want in addition add holiday:
For example   "*if  day and month is equal with 01.01 (1 January) * then will be "else" conditions.

html

```
        <span id="date_time"></span>
        <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = date_time('date_time');</script>
```

Script

```
 function date_time(id)
{
    date = new Date;
    year = date.getFullYear();
    month = date.getMonth();
    months = new Array('Janvāris', 'Februāris', 'Marts', 'Aprīlis', 'Maijs', 'Jūnījs', 'Jūlījs', 'Augusts', 'Septembris', 'Oktobris', 'Novembris', 'Decembris');
    d = date.getDate();
    day = date.getDay();
    days = new Array('Svētdiena', 'Pirmdiena', 'Otrdiena', 'Trešdiena', 'Ceturtdiena ', 'Piektdiena', 'Sestdiena');
    h = date.getHours();
    if(h<10)
    {
            h = "0"+h;
    }
    m = date.getMinutes();
    if(m<10)
    {
            m = "0"+m;
    }
    s = date.getSeconds();
    if(s<10)
    {
            s = "0"+s;
    }
      if ((day == 1 || day == 2 || day == 3 || day == 4 || day == 5 ) && h >= 9 && h <= 14) {
       result = 'Ir '+days[day]+' '+year+'.'+d+'.'+months[month]+' '+h+':'+m+':'+s+' ēdnīca ir atvērta!' ;
       document.getElementById("date_time").style.backgroundColor = '#27ae60';
  } else {
       result = 'Ir '+days[day]+' '+year+'.'+d+'.'+months[month]+' '+h+':'+m+':'+s+' ēdnīca ir slēgta!' ;
       document.getElementById("date_time").style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.85)';
  }
```

P.S I have this error

```
TypeError: timeDiv is null [Learn More]
checkTime file:///D:/Dators/Desktop/laiks/script.js:24:5
<anonymous> file:///D:/Dators/Desktop/laiks/script.js:28:66
```

Comment: `getDay()` will output a number between 0-6, not 1-7

Comment: It seems like `timeDiv` should be assigned when the page is ready. So, you can embed your code in `$(document).ready`. See here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

> But I want in addition add holiday: For example "*if day and month is equal with 01.01 (1 January) * then will be "else" conditions.

```
if (month !== 0 && d !== 1) {
  // ...
}
else {
  // Only executes on januari first
}
```

Comment: Problem is that: "month !== 0" it will show else condition for all month from first to the last day. And "d !== 1" it will show else conditions if every months day be "1";  But I need to be doing that, for example:
 
date 08.03  it shows else condition only this in the particular one calendar day. But all other month  and months day "8" be in true condition statement.

Comment: Ou never mind. I just (month !== 0 && d !== 1) replace with (month !== 0 || d !== 1 ). Thank you for the idea.

Comment: `&&` = 'and', `||` = 'or'

Comment: But for me works || = 'or'. But after an idea should work && = 'and'.